# Distinct and sort collection based on duplicate count

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have the following collection

```
$collection = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Design'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Art'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Comms'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Art'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Comms'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Comms'],
]);
```

I want only unique items in the collection and the collection should be sorted by number of duplicates. So an item which has most number of duplicates must appear on top as follows

```
$collection = collect([
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Comms'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Art'],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Design'],
    ]);
```

I can remove duplicates using `unique` method but cannot find a want to sort them.

Comment: perhaps you should group them first so you can get your count then map over them to get your final result?

Comment: how are you getting that collection. it's the query that need to be changed.

Comment: you can use `sortBy` method in collection to sort data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `mapWithKeys()`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys

```
$collection = $collection->groupBy('id')->mapWithKeys(function (Collection $row) {
    return [$row->count() => $row->first()];
})->sortKeysDesc();
```